# Ubuntu high power consumption with AMD processor

Tags: 20.04, power-management, battery, amd-graphics, fan

I had asked this question [before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213799/ubuntu-18-04-battery-life-with-amd-ryzen7-2700) for Ubuntu 18.04, then upgrade to 20.04. But issue still same.

My Processor spec :

```
AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 2700U APU Integrated Radeon Vega Graphics

Kernel : 5.4.25-050425-generic
```

Powertop and TLP enabled.

Power top stat

```
Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
  560 mW    641.2 µs/s     141.6        kWork          dbs_work_handler
  294 mW      4.0 ms/s      72.7        Interrupt      [67] amdgpu
  238 mW    603.6 µs/s      60.1        Timer          tick_sched_timer
  207 mW      4.6 ms/s      45.6        Process        [PID 2708] /usr/bin/gnom
  195 mW      6.7 ms/s      42.7        Process        [PID 2529] /usr/lib/xorg
 91.1 mW      3.7 ms/s      20.4        Process        [PID 13188] /usr/libexec
 61.8 mW    340.3 µs/s      15.5        Process        [PID 1390] /usr/bin/cont
 46.4 mW    284.9 µs/s      11.6        Process        [PID 667] [sdma0]
 42.3 mW    120.8 µs/s      10.7        kWork          psi_avgs_work
 38.6 mW    184.6 µs/s       9.7        Process        [PID 11] [rcu_sched]
 31.3 mW    447.7 µs/s       7.8        Process        [PID 12314] /usr/lib/fir
 31.2 mW    364.0 µs/s       7.8        Process        [PID 5526] /usr/bin/cont
```

TLP config :

```
TLP_ENABLE=1

CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=powersave

CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_AC=0
CPU_SCALING_MIN_FREQ_ON_BAT=0

SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1

RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=auto

RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_BAT=battery

RESTORE_THRESHOLDS_ON_BAT="1"
```

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217980/high-power-consumption-through-btusb-and-tick-sched-timer), its more related to radio drivers. And [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277518/hp-battery-backup-issue-on-amd-4600h-laptop) its not being answered.

When laptop is powered on and nothing is running, I could here fan is working (after few minutes booted)

[image: CPU temperature graph]

Comment: Even on my 5800U machine this is still the case.
On Windows I get ~8-12h of usage time, sometimes a bit less.
On linux the battery is done after ~2-4 hours...